# css flash card (no Javascript)

Tags: html, css

Why is the card flipping past the top edge?
Why is doesn't the border go all the way around the card?
Why can I still see the image when I flip the card to the back?

I posted a link to the codepen here
   [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXpJxV?editors=1100)

Here is a link to the size image I plan to use for all of the flash cards.

[image]

```css
label.rob-label {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  height: 150px;
  position: static;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

img {
  width: 90%;
}

.rob-card {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms;
  transition: all 600ms;
  z-index: 20;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
}

.rob-card div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.rob-card div>table {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.rob-card .back {
  color: #222;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

label.rob-label:hover .rob-card {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg);
  transform: rotateX(20deg);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, .2);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

:checked+.rob-card {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

label.rob-label:hover :checked+.rob-card {
  transform: rotateX(160deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(160deg);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
  <div>
    <label class="rob-label">
            <input type="checkbox"  />
            <div class="rob-card">
                <div class="front">
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/861x223"  alt= 
      "Sinus Brady - Arrhythmia The rate is slow and the rhythm is irregular">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                      <td>1</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
              <div class="back">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Sinus Brady - Arrhythmia The rate is slow and the
      rhythm is irregular</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
            </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The codepen link is just another imgur link

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you testing in? I made some changes and everything seems fine when I demo in Chrome.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzeJQM

```css
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

label.rob-label {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    display: block;
    width: 75%;
    height: 150px;
    position: static;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.rob-card {
    position: relative;
    height: 223px;
    width: 861px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms;
    transition: all 600ms;
    z-index: 20;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
}

.rob-card div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.rob-card .back {
    color: #222;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    background: #fff;
}



label.rob-label:hover .rob-card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg);
    transform: rotateX(20deg);
    box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(50,50,50,.2);
}

input {
    display: none;
}

:checked + .rob-card {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

label.rob-label:hover :checked + .rob-card {
    transform: rotateX(160deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(160deg);
    box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <div>
        <label class="rob-label">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="rob-card">
                <div class="front">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/861x223"  alt= "Sinus Brady - Arrhythmia The rate is slow and the rhythm is irregular">
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    <p>Sinus Brady - Arrhythmia The rate is slow and the rhythm is irregular</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I ran the original code in Firefox. I ran the code with your edits in Firefox as well and it worked! Thank you @JDewitt

Comment: The changes worked except when I tried to used images of a different size. Here's what I got: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PJVwvZ